# Convert Python dictionary to list of tuples

Tags: python

I am working on a small task that includes :

`my_filters = {'cat': 'apple,orange', 'day': '20200101,20200102'}`

It should convert it into a list of tuples like this :

```
[

[[('cat', '=', 'apple'), ('day', '=', '20200101')]]
[[('cat', '=', 'apple'), ('day', '=', '20200102')]]
[[('cat', '=', 'orange'), ('day', '=', '20200101')]]
[[('cat', '=', 'orange'), ('day', '=', '20200102')]]

]
```

My code is working fine for 2 keys :

```
def my_recursive_fun(i):
    results = []

    if i == 5:
        return ""
    if i <= 2:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            results.append([(list(my_filters.keys())[0], '=', my_filters['cat'].split(",")[0]),
                            (list(my_filters.keys())[1], '=', my_filters['day'].split(",")[1])])

        else:
            print("[\n")
            results.append([(list(my_filters.keys())[0], '=', my_filters['cat'].split(",")[0]),
                            (list(my_filters.keys())[1], '=', my_filters['day'].split(",")[0])])

    elif i <= 4:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            results.append([(list(my_filters.keys())[0], '=', my_filters['cat'].split(",")[1]),
                            (list(my_filters.keys())[1], '=', my_filters['day'].split(",")[1])])

            print(results)
            print("\n]")
            return ""
        else:
            results.append([(list(my_filters.keys())[0], '=', my_filters['cat'].split(",")[1]),
                            (list(my_filters.keys())[1], '=', my_filters['day'].split(",")[0])])

    print(results)
    my_recursive_fun(i + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_recursive_fun(1)
```

But when there are 4 keys in dictionary

```
my_filters = {'cat': 'apple,orange', 'day': '20200101,20200102', 'other': 'abc,cde', 'bis': '123,345'}
```

It should be like this :

```
[

[('cat','=','apple'),('day','=','20200101')],

[('cat','=','apple'),('day','=','20200102')],

[('cat','=','orange'),('day','=','20200101')],

[('cat','=','orange'),('day','=','20200102')],

[('other','=','abc'),('bis','=','123')],

[('other','=','abc'),('bis','=','345')],

[('other','=','cde'),('bis','=','123')],

[('other','=','cde'),('bis','=','345')]


]
```

So I am struggling when there are more keys in my dictionary. Thanks

Comment: This is a painful way to handle these cases.  You need to work through more exercises on generalizing problems.  One tool to help this particular application is the `itertools` package, especially the `product` method.  I hesitate to "help" you with this, because I see no reasonable application for your given output format: a list of lists of tuples of strange-looking strings ... ?  I'm worried that you need to back up and learn enough about data structures to properly apply whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Prune Honestly this is a school assignment and this is what instructions says to use

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  You'll need to clarify your restrictions: "this" has no clear referent.

Comment: Is the pairing of keys from the dictionary well defined? Because prior to Python 3.7, dictionaries were not ordered, so you might get `"cat"` paired with `"other"` and `"day"` paired with `"bis"` unless you have some special knowledge about those keys that lets you pair them up in the specified way. If you left it up to the order they appeared in the `dict`, you would get different results on different runs, due to hash randomization. Starting in Python 3.7, `dict` behavior changed (insertion order is preserved), though backwards compatible code may not want to take advantage of that fact yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my solution to a variation on your problem that might give you some ideas of how to go about it.  The differences in mine include: I use a real data structure for `my_filters`, i.e. lists instead of comma separated items in a string; this solution doesn't guarantee the order of results; this solution is destructive on `my_filters`:

```
my_filters = {
    'cat': ['apple', 'orange'],
    'day': ['20200101', '20200102'],
    'other': ['abc', 'cde'],
    'bis': [123, 345],
}

def recursive_filters(filters):
    my_results = []

    if filters:
        key, values = filters.popitem()

        results = recursive_filters(filters)

        for value in values:
            item = [key, '=', value]

            if results:
                for result in results:
                    my_results.append([*result, item])
            else:
                my_results.append([item])

    return my_results

print(*recursive_filters(my_filters), sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[['cat', '=', 'apple'], ['day', '=', '20200101'], ['other', '=', 'abc'], ['bis', '=', 123]]
[['cat', '=', 'orange'], ['day', '=', '20200101'], ['other', '=', 'abc'], ['bis', '=', 123]]
[['cat', '=', 'apple'], ['day', '=', '20200102'], ['other', '=', 'abc'], ['bis', '=', 123]]
[['cat', '=', 'orange'], ['day', '=', '20200102'], ['other', '=', 'abc'], ['bis', '=', 123]]
[['cat', '=', 'apple'], ['day', '=', '20200101'], ['other', '=', 'cde'], ['bis', '=', 123]]
[['cat', '=', 'orange'], ['day', '=', '20200101'], ['other', '=', 'cde'], ['bis', '=', 123]]
[['cat', '=', 'apple'], ['day', '=', '20200102'], ['other', '=', 'cde'], ['bis', '=', 123]]
[['cat', '=', 'orange'], ['day', '=', '20200102'], ['other', '=', 'cde'], ['bis', '=', 123]]
[['cat', '=', 'apple'], ['day', '=', '20200101'], ['other', '=', 'abc'], ['bis', '=', 345]]
[['cat', '=', 'orange'], ['day', '=', '20200101'], ['other', '=', 'abc'], ['bis', '=', 345]]
[['cat', '=', 'apple'], ['day', '=', '20200102'], ['other', '=', 'abc'], ['bis', '=', 345]]
[['cat', '=', 'orange'], ['day', '=', '20200102'], ['other', '=', 'abc'], ['bis', '=', 345]]
[['cat', '=', 'apple'], ['day', '=', '20200101'], ['other', '=', 'cde'], ['bis', '=', 345]]
[['cat', '=', 'orange'], ['day', '=', '20200101'], ['other', '=', 'cde'], ['bis', '=', 345]]
[['cat', '=', 'apple'], ['day', '=', '20200102'], ['other', '=', 'cde'], ['bis', '=', 345]]
[['cat', '=', 'orange'], ['day', '=', '20200102'], ['other', '=', 'cde'], ['bis', '=', 345]]
>
```

Hopefully this example will give your some ideas about how to approach a cleaner solution to your own problem.